# How to get Dialogflow to accept any input for a required entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

So I'm trying to create a dialogflow agent that works as a kind of interviewer.

For instance, at one point the agent asks "Do you have any food service experience?"

I've created entities "previous position," "previous employer," and "duration," and marked them as required. Using automatic expansion and providing sufficient example user input, the agent has no problem assigning things it hasn't seen before to these entities (for example, "Yes, I worked as an X at X company for X years" or "Yup, for X years I was an X at X company").

However, I'm running into problems with the prompts when a user doesn't provide all the required entities, which I assume will be quite common, for instance, a user might respond with simply "yes." If a user doesn't supply one of these entities, the prompt will ask "what was your position" and/or "Where did you work" and/or "how long did you work there." However, even with "automatic expansion" being checked, the system will not accept any user input that does not match one of the example entities I've provided ("Taco Bell", "4 years", "cook", "etc"), and it just keeps repeating the question. And of course I can't predict every possible response.

I know there are other ways of fixing this (such as prompting the user to enter the three categories in the original question or breaking it up into multiple intents), but I really want to find a way to fix this specific problem if it's possible in order for a less clunky chatbot.

So, is there any way to get the prompts for required entities to accept any input?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could ask a question which does not have multiple responses. You should phrase it in such a way that makes user automatically answer in a required way as your intent is designed. 
The way you have put your question: "Do you have any food service experience?"
Its answer will be mostly Yes or No.
So I will suggest you put two follow-up intents capturing `YES` and `NO` and in the `YES` follow-up intent capture the other required entities. Here you should mark them as `required`.
Also, in the original parent intent keep collecting the same entities but do not mark them as `required`. This way, you will automatically capture user responses like "Yes, I worked as an X at X company for X years".

Now, if the user only says "YES", you will have follow-up intent to capture entities and if the information is provided upfront in the parent entity, you can set the lifespan of context for the follow-up intent to "0" so that `YES` follow-up is not called.
You will need to play with contexts and multiple intents to capture all the scenarios.

Take a look at the following links to understand how to design conversations and follow best practices. These can be applied to almost every chatbot app.

[Dialogflow Design-Conversation](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/design-conversation)
[General Best Practice](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! The only part I'm struggling with is figuring out how to trigger the yes follow up ONLY if there are entities missing? You mention setting the context to zero, but how do I differentiate calling it or not calling it based on entities being filled or not? Relatedly, what if two out of the three entities are filled in the first intent...is there a way to trigger a followup that only asks the relevant questions?

Comment: If you make entities as optional in first intent, Yes or similar response will trigger the "YES" follow-up intent. You will need to enable webhook slot filing for capturing entities. If all entities are collected, then context can be set to 0 to trigger other other intents, else you will need to manipulate contexts to capture all the entities from the 2 intents. This will take some efforts from your side and it may be possible you have 2-3 intents capturing all the entities.

Comment: Better to start with an MVP and design your conversation so that user gets an idea what to speak. If the correct response is not provided by the user give them hints.

Comment: Ah gotcha! So there is not really a way to set the context to 0 iff all entities are collected without using webhook?

Comment: You can set the context to 0 from Dialogflow. But in that case, it would be every time. What you need is based on logic which is better through Webhook.